# Filtering data from CSV file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, filter

I have huge csv file where first line contains headers of the data. Because the file size I can't open it with excel or similar. I need to filter rows what I only need. I would want to create new csv file which contains only data where Header3 = "TextHere". Everything else is filtered away.

I have tried in PowerShell Get-Content Select-String | Out-File 'newfile.csv' but it lost header row and also messed up with the data putting data in to wrong fields. There is included empty fields in the data and I believe that is messing it. When I tried Get-Content -First or -Last data seemed to be in order.

I have no experience handling big data files or powershell before. Also other options besides PowerShell is also possible if it is free to use as "non-commercial use"

Comment: I have never done it the way you are describing but I would check out `Convertto-CSV` and `Add-Content`. Could use `Get-Content` to get the data, select what you want, convert it, and add it to file

Comment: take a look at the streamreader/writer stuff. that would allow you to read in a line, test for your value, and then write it out to a new file. you MAY be able to use the `-ReadCount` parameter of `Get-Content` to process things in chunks if that seems more to your taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this (modify your delimiter if necessary):

```
import-csv "c:\temp\yourfile.csv" -delimiter ";" | where Header3 -eq "TextHere" | export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -delimiter ";" -notype
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seemed to work like charm! Only issue what I first had was that I had to remove (") from text, so it was in form where Header3 -eq TextHere. I assume that this is basic knowledge but if any other newbs like me reads this could help a little.